# ToggleButtons, Flutter: How to change border color and border radius

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, styling

I have 3 ToggleButtons and I'm trying to figure out how to change the color of the selected button's border. As you can see in my picture, the green button on the left has a very hard to see light blue border around it since it is the selected button. I would like to know how I can change this color and also how I can round the border's corners.

[image]

If it helps, 'CryptoCard' is made with the Card class.

Here is my code:

```
Center(
                          child: ToggleButtons(
                              borderWidth: 0,
                              splashColor: Colors.yellow,
                              renderBorder: false,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                CryptoCard(
                                    selectedCurrency,
                                    snapshot.connectionState ==
                                            ConnectionState.waiting
                                        ? '---'
                                        : coinData[0],
                                    'Bitcoin'),
                                CryptoCard(
                                    selectedCurrency,
                                    snapshot.connectionState ==
                                            ConnectionState.waiting
                                        ? '---'
                                        : coinData[1],
                                    'Ethereum'),
                                CryptoCard(
                                    selectedCurrency,
                                    snapshot.connectionState ==
                                            ConnectionState.waiting
                                        ? '---'
                                        : coinData[2],
                                    'Litecoin'),
                              ],
                              onPressed: (int index) {
                                setState(() {
                                  for (int buttonIndex = 0;
                                      buttonIndex < isSelectedCrypto.length;
                                      buttonIndex++) {
                                    if (buttonIndex == index) {
                                      isSelectedCrypto[buttonIndex] = true;
                                      selectedCrypto =
                                          cryptoAbbreviation[buttonIndex];
                                      print("selectedCrypto");
                                      print(selectedCrypto);
                                    } else {
                                      isSelectedCrypto[buttonIndex] = false;
                                    }
                                  }
                                });

                                futureData = getData();
                              },
                              isSelected: isSelectedCrypto))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ToggleButton has a property selectedBorderColor which you can use to set the border color of your selected button. You can use a custom widget to give rounded border to each individual button.

[image]

Please see the code below :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = const Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<bool> isSelected = List.generate(6, (index) => false);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ToggleButtons(
          children: [
            CustomIcon(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
              isSelected: isSelected[0],
              bgColor: const Color(0xfff44336),
            ),
            CustomIcon(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.call),
              isSelected: isSelected[1],
              bgColor: const Color(0xffE91E63),
            ),
            CustomIcon(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.cake),
              isSelected: isSelected[2],
              bgColor: const Color(0xff9C27B0),
            ),
            CustomIcon(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
              isSelected: isSelected[3],
              bgColor: const Color(0xff673AB7),
            ),
            CustomIcon(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.accessibility),
              isSelected: isSelected[4],
              bgColor: const Color(0xff3F51B5),
            ),
            CustomIcon(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.analytics),
              isSelected: isSelected[5],
              bgColor: const Color(0xff2196F3),
            ),
          ],
          onPressed: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              for (int buttonIndex = 0;
                  buttonIndex < isSelected.length;
                  buttonIndex++) {
                if (buttonIndex == index) {
                  isSelected[buttonIndex] = !isSelected[buttonIndex];
                } else {
                  isSelected[buttonIndex] = false;
                }
              }
            });
          },
          isSelected: isSelected,
          selectedColor: Colors.amber,
          renderBorder: false,
          fillColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomIcon extends StatefulWidget {
  final Icon icon;
  final bool isSelected;
  final Color bgColor;

  const CustomIcon(
      {Key key,
      this.icon,
      this.isSelected = false,
      this.bgColor = Colors.green})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  _CustomIconState createState() => _CustomIconState();
}

class _CustomIconState extends State<CustomIcon> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 47,
      height: 47,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: widget.isSelected
            ? Border.all(
                color: const Color(0xffC5CAE9),
              )
            : null,
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 32,
          width: 32,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: widget.bgColor,
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(5),
            ),
          ),
          child: widget.icon,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried using selectedBorderColor but it doesn't change anything for me. My outer border is still a faint blue when I specify a selectedBorderColor. Also, I'm asking how to round the corners of the outer border of the button, not how to round the button's corners.

Comment: You can round the border of the entire ToggleButton by setting the borderRadius property. Note this will apply to the border of the entire ToggleButton not the individual buttons. I've made a dartpad with the above code on this URL - https://dartpad.dev/5897768e2ba049807141f783d5fdbfc0

Comment: I already have rounded corners on my buttons. I'm asking how to change the color of the faint blue surrounding the selected button and how to round the corners of the faint blue surrounding the selected button. Your dartpad example has the same faint blue color surrounding the selected button just like mine does.

Comment: Are you asking about the splash color? Please see the Dartpad again, I've updated the code a bit - https://dartpad.dev/5897768e2ba049807141f783d5fdbfc0

Comment: When you hover your mouse over one of your buttons, a light blue box appears around your button. I want to know how to change the color of that box and how to round its corners.

Comment: When you hover the faint color that you see is the hover color. The following are the various colors you see during tap or pointer hovers. 

 highlightColor → The highlight color for the button's InkWell.
 hoverColor → The color to use for filling the button when the button has a pointer hovering over it.
 focusColor → The color to use for filling the button when the button has input focus.
 splashColor → The splash color for the button's InkWell.

Refer https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ToggleButtons-class.html . Also check https://dartpad.dev/5897768e2ba049807141f783d5fdbfc0

Comment: Can you show how to change the color in your code? I tried all of those already and it doesn't change anything for me. I've read through the docs before posting.

Comment: Already updated the code here https://dartpad.dev/5897768e2ba049807141f783d5fdbfc0

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it is not the best but here is my code for this maybe it will help someone out there.
if you need **only need one selected button to be colorized** in different colour like this

### [image]
[image]
[image]

```
Color mColor = Color(0xFF6200EE),mColor0 = Color(0xFF6200EE),mColor1 = Color(0xFF6200EE);
final isSelected = <bool>[false, false, false];
```

then

```
ToggleButtons(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.60),
              selectedColor: mColor,
              selectedBorderColor: mColor0,
              fillColor: mColor1.withOpacity(0.08),
              splashColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.12),
              hoverColor: Color(0xFF6200EE).withOpacity(0.04),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
              constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 36.0),
              isSelected: isSelected,
              onPressed: (index) {
                // Respond to button selection
                setState(() {
                  isSelected[0] = false;
                  isSelected[1] = false;
                  isSelected[2] = false;
                  if (index == 0) {
                    mColor = Colors.blue;
                    mColor0 = Colors.blue;
                    mColor1 = Colors.blue;
                  }
                  if (index == 1) {
                    mColor = Colors.green;
                    mColor0 = Colors.green;
                    mColor1 = Colors.green;
                  }
                  if (index == 2) {
                    mColor = Colors.red;
                    mColor0 = Colors.red;
                    mColor1 = Colors.red;
                  }
                  isSelected[index] = !isSelected[index];
                });
              },
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'BUTTON 1',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'BUTTON 2',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'BUTTON 3',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```